# A GUID disk partition cannot be removed

Tags: macos, partitioning

I have a disk GUID partitioned into four parts. But one of the disk partition cannot be removed. I want to know how to remove this partition and why this happened.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Have you tried booting with a Linux LiveUSB and using gnome-disk? http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gnome-disks.1.html

Comment: @K7AAY Well, I want to know can I solve this problem on MacOS. And what happened to this, why it cannot be removed.

Comment: Then you may wish to ask at the MacOS specific site https://apple.stackexchange.com/ ... but I thought you also wanted a solution. " I want to know how to remove this partition" If I had a complete solution, I would have posted it as a solution, below.

Comment: @K7AAY Ok, thank you. But in my opinion, the first thing is to know why, and then try to solve this problem. Four partitions, but only the specific one cannot be removed. That is unreasonable.